# jQuery Image Hover Swap Not Working

Tags: jquery

So for this example, I have a source image (image.jpg) and another image that I want to swap on hover (image-hover.jpg).

The onmouseover event is triggered, but only reveals the image-hover.jpg for less than a second. Even though I'm still hovering over the image, it quickly swaps back out to default image (image.jpg).

Any ideas why this is happening?

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
 jQuery(".jig-overflow img").addClass("img-swap");
 
 var aPreLoad = new Array();
 var sTempSrc;
 var aImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

 for (var i = 0; i < aImages.length; i++) {  
  if (aImages[i].className == 'img-swap') {
   var src = aImages[i].getAttribute('src');
   var ftype = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('.'), src.length);
   var hsrc = src.replace(ftype, '-hover'+ftype);

   aImages[i].setAttribute('hsrc', hsrc);
   
   aPreLoad[i] = new Image();
   aPreLoad[i].src = hsrc;
   
   aImages[i].onmouseover = function() {
    sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src');
    this.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('hsrc'));
   }
   
   aImages[i].onmouseout = function() {
    if (!sTempSrc) sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src').replace('-hover'+ftype, ftype);
    this.setAttribute('src', sTempSrc);
   }
  }
 }
});
```

This is an example of the div that the element is enclosed in:

```
<div class="jig-overflow" style="opacity: 1; width: 364px; height: 206px;">
    <a target="_self" href="#" style="cursor: default;" class="jig-loaded">            
        <img src="placeholder.jpg" class="img-swap">
        <div class="jig-overlay-wrapper" style="display: none;">
            <div class="jig-overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jig-caption-wrapper jig-cw-role-real" style="bottom: auto; top: 87px;">
            <div class="jig-caption" style="display: none;">
                <div class="jig-caption-title">Text Here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you've got 2 images: `my-image.png` and `my-image-hover.png`. You're also using jQuery, so you can cut a lot of your code down.

Here's my solution

```
jQuery(function($){ // Shorthand, also means we can use $ from now on, instead of jQuery
    // For every <img> inside something with the class .jig-overflow add the class .img-swap
    $(".jig-overflow img").addClass("img-swap");

    // For each <img> with the class of .img-swap ...
    $("img.img-swap").each(function(){

        // $(this) is the <img> we're currently working with
        var original_src = $(this).attr('src'); // Get original src
        var file_type = original_src.substring(original_src.lastIndexOf('.'), original_src.length); // Get file type
        var hover_src = original_src.replace(file_type, '-hover'+file_type); // Generate hover filename

        // jQuery has a data API which allows us to add HTML5 data to an element. So set the original_src attribute to original_src, and do the same with the hover one
        $(this).data('original_src', original_src);
        $(this).data('hover_src', hover_src);
    });

    // Add mouseover and mouseout event listeners
    $("img.img-swap").on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('hover_src')); // Replace the SRC attbute with the one we set in the data attibute
    });

    $("img.img-swap").on('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('original_src')); // Revert it
    });

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Laazuha5/

Comment: Thanks dotty. But still the same issue - hover image appears briefly, but disappears after that, even though mouse is still on top of element.

I updated the original posting to include the HTML section that is is part of. Maybe there is something I'm overlooking related to this?

Comment: What browser you using? Both examples yours and mine) work in Safari and Chrome.